# Is it possible to code an X-Sampa to IPA interpreter in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm just getting started with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), and while I have been reading through the documentation, I've not yet found any suggestion that hints it is possible to accomplish this task.

I want to be able to type in [X-SAMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA) text and have it replaced by its corresponding [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). To set off the [X-SAMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA), I intend to bracket it with `X[` and `]`. Thus, if I type `X[T@]` and press a magic key, it would be replaced with `/θə/`.

1. Is this possible at all with [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com)?
2. How would it be done, if so? Again, I'm not finding clues in the documentation. (Note: I can find the way to declare the magic key; it's doing the "smart replacement" that is not apparent.)

Comment: [Hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)

Comment: @user3419297 - Yes, but how to handle the more-or-less intelligent parsing? The problem with X-SAMPA is that it uses basic text - in the character range 0x20 to 0x7E - to encode IPA. That's why I'm bracketing it with `X[]`; that won't be found in the X-SAMPA. What I need is for AHK to "pick up" everything between the brackets, and convert each X-SAMPA representation into its corresponding IPA, individually - but not where I have to bracket each X-SAMPA representation individually.

Comment: Main problem is not parsing, but how to get the whole string as variable in the first place. So e.g. you'll need to put the whole string into clipboard first to get to the contents from AHK.  I'd just recommend using a text editor with scripting support, e.g. Notepad++. There are plugins like Pythonscript, it will be much simpler.

Comment: @MikhailV - There are several programs that I need this functionality in, and opening a Notepad++ and constantly cutpasting is ... inconvenient at best, and really not much better than having an X-SAMPA to IPA webpage open to copypaste from. AHK at least has the virtue of working in most if not all of the contexts I need it in.

Comment: If you need this functionality across various apps - then yes, you should use AHK approach. (it should be stated in the question though). So the first question in this case should be - how to retrieve the text that is being typed  into an AHK string variable. Generally this is the question, whether you can select and copy the needed text bit to clipboard. So I suggest better ask this question. The proposed 'hotstrings' may solve it but it is hard to manage and not always stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; Save Script with UTF-8-Bom Encoding

xsampa :=   ComObjCreate("Scripting.Dictionary")
; Lower, Uppercase, Symbols, Diacritics - X-Sampa Dictionary 
;  - Found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA
xsampa.item("A")    := "ɑ", xsampa.item("}}}")  := "͈"
xsampa.item("b_<")  := "ɓ", xsampa.item("B")    := "β", xsampa.item("L\")   := "ʟ"
xsampa.item("d_<")  := "ɗ", xsampa.item("B\")   := "ʙ", xsampa.item("M")    := "ɯ"
xsampa.item("g_<")  := "ɠ", xsampa.item("C")    := "ç", xsampa.item("M\")   := "ɰ"
xsampa.item("h\")   := "ɦ", xsampa.item("D")    := "ð", xsampa.item("N")    := "ŋ"
xsampa.item("j\")   := "ʝ", xsampa.item("E")    := "ɛ", xsampa.item("N\")   := "ɴ"
xsampa.item("l`")   := "ɭ", xsampa.item("F")    := "ɱ", xsampa.item("O")    := "ɔ"
xsampa.item("l\")   := "ɺ", xsampa.item("G")    := "ɣ", xsampa.item("O\")   := "ʘ"
xsampa.item("n``")  := "ɳ", xsampa.item("G\")   := "ɢ", xsampa.item("P")    := "ʋ"
xsampa.item("p\")   := "ɸ", xsampa.item("G\_<") := "ʛ", xsampa.item("Q")    := "ɒ"
xsampa.item("r``")  := "ɽ", xsampa.item("H")    := "ɥ", xsampa.item("R")    := "ʁ"
xsampa.item("r\")   := "ɹ", xsampa.item("H\")   := "ʜ", xsampa.item("R\")   := "ʀ"
xsampa.item("r\``") := "ɻ", xsampa.item("I")    := "ɪ", xsampa.item("S")    := "ʃ"
xsampa.item("s``")  := "ʂ", xsampa.item("I\")   := "ɪ̈", xsampa.item("T")   := "θ"
xsampa.item("t``")  := "ʈ", xsampa.item("J")    := "ɲ", xsampa.item("U")    := "ʊ"
xsampa.item("s\")   := "ɕ", xsampa.item("J\")   := "ɟ", xsampa.item("U\")   := "ʊ̈"
xsampa.item("v\")   := "ʋ", xsampa.item("J\_<") := "ʄ", xsampa.item("V")    := "ʌ"
xsampa.item("x\")   := "ɧ", xsampa.item("K")    := "ɬ", xsampa.item("W")    := "ʍ"
xsampa.item("z``")  := "ʐ", xsampa.item("K\")   := "ɮ", xsampa.item("X")    := "χ"
xsampa.item("z\")   := "ʑ", xsampa.item("L")    := "ʎ", xsampa.item("X\")   := "ħ"
xsampa.item("Y")    := "ʏ", xsampa.item("Z")    := "ʒ", xsampa.item("""")   := "ˈ"
xsampa.item("%")    := "ˌ", xsampa.item("'")    := "ʲ", xsampa.item(":")    := "ː"
xsampa.item(":\")   := "ˑ", xsampa.item("-")    := " ", xsampa.item("@")    := "ə"
xsampa.item("@\")   := "ɘ", xsampa.item("{")    := "æ", xsampa.item("}")    := "ʉ"
xsampa.item("1")    := "ɨ", xsampa.item("2")    := "ø", xsampa.item("3")    := "ɜ"
xsampa.item("3\")   := "ɞ", xsampa.item("4")    := "ɾ", xsampa.item("5")    := "ɫ"
xsampa.item("6")    := "ɐ", xsampa.item("7")    := "ɤ", xsampa.item("8")    := "ɵ"
xsampa.item("9")    := "œ", xsampa.item("&")    := "ɶ", xsampa.item("?")    := "ʔ"
xsampa.item("?\")   := "ʕ", xsampa.item("<\")   := "ʢ", xsampa.item(">\")   := "ʡ"
xsampa.item("^")    := "ꜛ", xsampa.item("!")    := "ꜜ", xsampa.item("!\")   := "ǃ"
xsampa.item("|")    := "|", xsampa.item("|\")   := "ǀ", xsampa.item("||")   := "‖"
xsampa.item("|\|\") := "ǁ", xsampa.item("=\")   := "ǂ", xsampa.item("-\")   := "‿"
xsampa.item("_""")  :=  "̈", xsampa.item("_+")   :=  "̟", xsampa.item("_/") := "̌"
xsampa.item("_-")   := "̠" , xsampa.item("_/")   :=  "̌", xsampa.item("_0")   := "̥"
xsampa.item("=")    := "̩" , xsampa.item("_=")   := "̩" , xsampa.item("_>")   := "ʼ"
xsampa.item("_?\")  := "ˤ", xsampa.item("_\")   := "̂" , xsampa.item("_^")   := "̯"
xsampa.item("_}")   := "̚" , xsampa.item("``")   := "˞" , xsampa.item("~")    := "̃"
xsampa.item("_~")   := "̃" , xsampa.item("_A")   := "̘" , xsampa.item("_a")   := "̺"
xsampa.item("_B")   := "̏" , xsampa.item("_B_L") := "᷅" , xsampa.item("_c")   := "̜"
xsampa.item("_d")   := "̪" , xsampa.item("_e")   := "̴" , xsampa.item("<F>")  := "↘"
xsampa.item("_F")   := "̂" , xsampa.item("_G")   := "ˠ", xsampa.item("_H")   := "́"
xsampa.item("_H_T") := "᷄" , xsampa.item("_h")   := "ʰ", xsampa.item("_j")   := "ʲ"
xsampa.item("_k")   := "̰" , xsampa.item("_L")   := "̀" , xsampa.item("_l")   := "ˡ"
xsampa.item("_M")   := "̄" , xsampa.item("_m")   := "̻" , xsampa.item("_N")   := "̼"
xsampa.item("_n")   := "ⁿ", xsampa.item("_O")   := "̹" , xsampa.item("_o")   := "̞"
xsampa.item("_q")   := "̙" , xsampa.item("<R>")  := "↗", xsampa.item("_R")   := "̌"
xsampa.item("_R_F") := "᷈" , xsampa.item("_r")   := "̝" , xsampa.item("_T")   := "̋"
xsampa.item("_t")   := "̤" , xsampa.item("_v")   := "̬" , xsampa.item("_w")   := "ʷ"
xsampa.item("_X")   := "̆" , xsampa.item("_x")   := "̽" 


:*b0:x[::   
    While (e != "EndKey:]"){
        Input, key, v, ]{BS}{Enter}{Esc}
        e := ErrorLevel
        typed .= key, key := ""
        If (e == "EndKey:Backspace")
            typed := SubStr(typed, 1, (StrLen(typed)-1))
        if (e == "EndKey:Escape" || e == "EndKey:Enter") {
            SendInput % "{BackSpace " (e == "EndKey:Enter" ? StrLen(typed)+3 
                                                           : StrLen(typed)+2) "}"
            newText := typed := e := ""
            return
        }
    }

    NewText := xsampaParse(xsampa, typed)

    SendInput % "{BackSpace " StrLen(typed)+3 "}" newText
    newText := typed := e := ""
    Hotstring("Reset")
return


xsampaParse(xsampa, typed, NewText:="", pos:=4) {

    if (StrLen(typed)) { 
        if (xsampa.Exists(SubStr(typed, 1, pos))) {
            newText .= xsampa.item(SubStr(typed, 1, pos)) 
            typed := SubStr(typed, pos+1)
            return xsampaParse(xsampa, typed, NewText)
        } else if (pos == 1) {            
            newText .= SubStr(typed, 1, pos)
            typed := SubStr(typed, pos+1)
            return xsampaParse(xsampa, typed, NewText)
        } else return xsampaParse(xsampa, typed, NewText, --pos)

    } else Return newText    
}
```